# Trying to get new 144hz monitor to work

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I recently received the **AOC 24G2SE** monitor as a gift which is capable of 144hz and I am trying to make it work with my other monitor (**LG 24EN43**) and my rather old **Gigabyte Sabre 17** laptop.

I have been using the LG monitor and my laptop for a few years now and I got my first chance to try a setup

So the problem I'm currently having is that I can't get the AOC monitor to be set to 144hz and there is a lot of screen tearing and a lot of frame drops.

Some things I have tried:

1. Since my laptop doesn't have a display port and only has 1 HDMI port, I bought a JCA365 from J5create which has 2 female HDMI ports and outputs through USB-C. Tried it and it works, but I was only able to set the AOC monitor to a maximum of 120hz and it would constantly drop a lot of frames and just overall cause a lot of performance issues. I tried 60hz, there was barely any lag, but everything comes up fuzzy.
2. Did some research and found that maybe the problem was from not using the display port of the AOC 24G2SE. I was recommended by J5create to use the JCD401 dock which is capable of taking in 1 HDMI and 1 display port and outputs through a USB-C. Went out and bought it and tried it and connected the HDMI from the LG monitor and the display port from the AOC and it would not even show anything on either monitors. I was wondering if there was a problem with the JCD401, so I tried sticking a USB stick into it and it wouldn't even pop up. So I contacted J5create again and they told me that because my laptop doesn't have "Native Video Output" the JCD401 is not compatible with my laptop.

Now currently I'm stuck, I tried looking for some other adaptors, asking their respective support if it would be compatible with my laptop, but they all just tell me "If your PC is able to take in a USB-C it will work". But because of what happened prior I really don't want to spend money on devices I am told will work, but end up duds.

My laptop may be old and no options may be viable, but I really want this setup to work.

Any recommendations for my situation would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: * they told me that because my laptop doesn't have "Native Video Output"*   They're probably wrong and even if true that has nothing to do with other USB devices.

Comment: Does your laptop not have 2 mini display ports?  What is the full model of your laptop?